# What does the MediaPlayer message "internal/external state mismatch corrected" mean?

Tags: android

I've been doing some pretty complex things with the MediaPlayer. Unlike https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399286/android-media-player-internal-external-state-mismatch, I'm only working with audio, not video. The MediaPlayer class is notoriously fragile and unintuitive, so it's difficult to work around its quirks. I've been doing the best I can, but still run into difficult-to-diagnose bugs.

In this case, I occasionally see the error message "internal/external state mismatch corrected". I have no idea why. I'm running multiple MediaPlayers simultaneously, using MediaRecorder and then playing it in a MediaPlayer, stopping and starting and resetting and seeking... at least some of the time it seems to occur after start().

Is this a bug in Android, or am I doing something wrong? Can anyone tell me what this error message represents, and if there's something I should be doing differently or if I can safely ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that answers your question, but looking [at the source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp), it seems like the state was `MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED` although the player stopped playing already, and Stagefright changes the state to `MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED`.

There's seem to be an open bug for that: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9732

Comment: Hm, I'm still not sure about that then--it could either mean the MediaPlayer implementation is buggy and stops without changing from MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED to MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED... or that I'm doing something wrong that cause the MediaPlayer to stop unnaturally, circumventing stop() and normal completion. Wish I knew which! As for the bug report, that's for playing MIDI files with isLooping set. Nice thought, but neither of those conditions apply in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the "internal/external state mismatch corrected" errors to stop by calling MediaPlayer.reset() immediately after instantiating the MediaPlayer object:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.reset();
```