# Approaches to Android MediaPlayer state mismatch error on isPlaying()?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out how to address the Android MediaPlayer's "state mismatch" error which is occasionally thrown during audio playback when I try to pause.

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545205/what-means-the-message-internal-external-state-mismatch-corrected-at-the-media), there is a known issue with the Android MediaPlayer occasionally throwing an error on a call to `isPlaying()`

The result is a call to `pause()` or `isPlaying()` causes the `MediaPlayer` to stop responding to requests until it is reset.

Here's a log from when this error occurs:

```
I/MusicPlaybackService﹕ I got a pause message
E/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ internal/external state mismatch corrected
```

[Here's a github bug with more details related to this issue](https://github.com/smithdtyler/prettygoodmusicplayer/issues/91).

My current solution is **incredibly ugly**:

```
/**
 * Pause the currently playing song.
 */
private synchronized void pause() {
    try{
        // this is a hack, but it seems to be the most consistent way to address the problem
        // this forces the media player to check its current state before trying to pause.
        int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        mp.seekTo(position);
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.w(TAG, "Caught exception while trying to pause ", e);
    }
    updateNotification();
}
```

My theory is that the MediaPlayer loses track of its own state, and calling `start()` and `seekTo()` before pausing will force the MediaPlayer to reset its concept of its own state.

This solution is hacky and appears to be causing [other issues](https://github.com/smithdtyler/prettygoodmusicplayer/issues/94).

Google appears to have marked the [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9732) for this behavior as Obsolete.

I'm testing this on an LG G3 running android 5.0.1.

Thus my question is: **What should I do about this?** Is there a better way to force the MediaPlayer to check its own state before pausing?

Comment: The issue was tagged obsolete by a script because the original report was before Android 2.3. The comment on this suggests opening a new one.

Comment: Have you tried calling mp.reset() right after instantiating the object? It fixes the issue for some people without causing more. I haven't tried this myself so yeah.

Comment: @ManPerson I will try this. I was hesitant to do a reset because I don't want to re-start the song when a pause occurs.

Comment: I think you only have to do it when you instantiate the MediaPlayer object and that's it

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best solution I've been able to come up with. It appears to address the issue with pausing, and hasn't caused any unintended side effects:

```
private synchronized void pause() {
    // Sometimes the call to isPlaying can throw an error "internal/external state mismatch corrected"
    // When this happens, I think the player moves itself to "paused" even though it's still playing.
    try{
        // this is a hack, but it seems to be the most consistent way to address the problem
        int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        mp.stop();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.seekTo(position);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.w(TAG, "Caught exception while trying to pause ", e);
    }
}
```

This solution forces a reset of the state machine without resetting the entire media player, and without calling `play`.

Annotated [state machine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for reference:

[image]